# Get a url for a file generated by file_put_contents();

Tags: php, laravel, file

I'm trying to get the url of a file saved by file_put_contents() function.

Below is what I tried instead I get a resource output. How do I get data from the resource.

```
$file = file_put_contents($name, $image);

$link = fopen($name, 'r', TRUE);
dd($link);
```

Resource

```
stream resource @418 ▼
  timed_out: false
  blocked: true
  eof: false
  wrapper_type: "plainfile"
  stream_type: "STDIO"
  mode: "r"
  unread_bytes: 0
  seekable: true
  uri: "C:\xampp\htdocs\fedex\public\labels\1556192611.png"
  options: []
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You know the base URL, and the path which you stored the file under, no? Then what else do you need? _“How do I get data from the resource.”_ - you don’t get any HTTP URL from this, because you are operating in the _file system_ here. URLs and file system paths _can_ (partially) overlap, but they don’t have to.

Comment: Why not use Laravel's [File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem)?

Comment: @04FS basically I want to generate a link to the file saved by the `file_put_contents()` function. Yes I do know the path to the file, but I want to generate it for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
$fp = fopen($name, "r"); // file pointer
if ($fp){
    while (!feof($fp)){ // feof — Tests for end-of-file on a file pointer
        $line = fgets($fp); // fgets — Gets line from file pointer
        if(strpos($line, 'uri:') !== false){ // checking matching of string
            $result[] = $line;
        } 
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
print_r($result);
```

I have kept inline documentation for readability

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check [Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem) class.
or you can just save it in a public folder like:

```
$file = file_put_contents(public_path().$name, $image);
$link = asset($name);
```